# How do you serve a static html file using a go web server?

Tags: go

How do you serve index.html (or some other static HTML file) using a go web server?

I just want a basic, static HTML file (like an article, for example) which I can serve from a go web server.  The HTML should be modifiable outside of the go program, as it would be in the case while using HTML templates.

This is my web server which only hosts hard-coded text ("Hello world!").

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello world!")
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

That task is very easy with Golang net/http package.

All You need to do is:

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

assuming that static files are in folder named `static` in the root directory of the project.

If it's in folder `static`, you'll have `index.html` file calling `http://localhost:3000/` which will result in rendering that index file instead of listing all the files availible.

Additionally, calling any other file in that folder (for example `http://localhost:3000/clients.html`) will show that file, properly rendered by the browser (at least Chrome, Firefox and Safari :))

### UPDATE: serving files from url different than "/"

If You want to serve files, say from folder `./public` under url: `localhost:3000/static` You have to **use additional function**: `func StripPrefix(prefix string, h Handler) Handler` like this:

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

Thanks to that, all your files from `./public` are avalible under `localhost:3000/static`

Without `http.StripPrefix` function, if you would try to access file `localhost:3000/static/test.html`, the server would look for it in `./public/static/test.html`

This is because the server treats the whole URI as a relative path to the file.

Fortunately, it's easily solved with the built-in function.

Comment: why handle pattern is `/static/` not `/static`?

Comment: How do you serve a static html file if the file is elsewhere on the hard-drive, outside the project entirely?

Comment: I attempted it from absolute path: /Users/username/path/to/file, and it worked successfully just the same.

Comment: @Bryce, because you want to match the complete subtree ([see also](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)). With just `/static` as pattern (and strip-prefix) only `http://example.org/static` requests would be served by the FileServer handler. That means requests to `http://example.org/static/` and `http://example.org/static/foo.css` etc. would fail or be handled by another handler.

Comment: Is it possible to serve static files together with rest routes?

Comment: I think the path needs to be "/*" to catch all.

Comment: ```package main

import (
    "net/http"
)


func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}```

This happens to work.

Comment: The handle pattern should be: 

`http.Handle("/static", http.StripPrefix("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))))`

Answer (score 26):

I prefer using `http.ServeFile` for this over `http.FileServer`. I wanted directory browsing disabled, a proper 404 if files are missing and an easy way to special case the index file. This way, you can just drop the built binary into a folder and it will serve everything relative to that binary. Of course, you can use `strings.Replace` on `p` if you have the files stored in another directory.

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Now Listening on 80")
    http.HandleFunc("/", serveFiles)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil))
}

func serveFiles(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.URL.Path)
    p := "." + r.URL.Path
    if p == "./" {
        p = "./static/index.html"
    }
    http.ServeFile(w, r, p)
}
```

Comment: for folks copy pasting this snippet, there is a "file path traversal" security bug in the code snippet above. it allows reading arbitrary files from the server

see  https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal

Answer (score 13):

If you only want to serve 1 file and not a full directory, you can use [http.ServeFile](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile)

```golang
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "index.html")
})
```

Comment: My requirement was just to serve a single HTML file .. and I went thru the whole http.FileSystem related stuff.. this worked.. thanks a lot..

Answer (score 8):

> NOT a FTP server: That is something different than what I intended, which would be to serve the `index.html` homepage, like a normal web server would. Like, when I go to mydomain.com in my browser, I want `index.html` rendered.

That is mainly what "[**Writing Web Applications**](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/)" describes, and what a project like [**hugo**](http://spf13.com/project/hugo/) (static html site generator) does.

It is about reading a file, and responsing with a ContentType "text/html":

```
func (server *Server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := server.renderFile(w, r.URL.Path)
    if err != nil {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNotFound)
        server.fn404(w, r)
    }
}
```

with `renderFile()` essentially reading and setting the right type:

```
 file, err = ioutil.ReadFile(server.MediaPath + filename)
 if ext != "" {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", mime.TypeByExtension(ext))
 }
```

Comment: Perhaps I did not ask the question correctly.  Isn't this providing a means of building a file server, similar to a FTP server?  That is something different than what I intended, which would be to serve the index.html homepage, like a normal web server would.  Like, when I go to mydomain.com in my browser, I want index.html rendered.  I don't want to see a directory of files stored on the web server's file system.  I can edit question to reword if my question was misleading.

Comment: @nairware ok, I have rewritten the answer

Comment: So there is no way to create a classic website under Go that uses HTML pages and server pages? Must it either be a static website or a template-based website?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the Gorilla Mux Router to server static files.
Assuming you have a static folder and an index.html file in the root.

```
import  "github.com/gorilla/mux"

  func main(){
    router := mux.NewRouter()
        fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
        router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Example how custom serve mp3 file:

```
r := http.NewServeMux()
r.HandleFunc("/file/*", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    // Prepare file path
    pathFile := strings.ReplaceAll(r.RequestURI, "/file/", "./my_path/")
    f, err := os.Open(pathFile)
    if f == nil || err != nil {
        return
    }

    // Read file into memory
    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error file bytes")
        return
    }

    // Check mime type
    mime := http.DetectContentType(fileBytes)
    if mime != "audio/mpeg" {
        log.Println("Error file type")
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w, "Error file type")
        return
    }

    // Custom headers
    r.Header.Add("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg")
    r.Header.Add("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Description", "File Transfer")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=file.mp3")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    r.Header.Add("Expires", "0")
    r.Header.Add("Pragma", "public")
    r.Header.Add("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(fileBytes)))
    http.ServeFile(w, r, pathFile)
})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":80", r))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easy in golang as:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
}
```

`

You can just do this and make sure to keep your HTML file as `index.html`

Answer (score 0):

This will serve the index.html file (if you have in the root) to the browser on localhost:8080

```
func main() {
    port := flag.String("p", "8080", "port to serve on")
    directory := flag.String("d", ".", "static file folder")
    flag.Parse()

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(*directory)))

    log.Printf("Serving %s on HTTP port: %s\n", *directory, *port)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+*port, nil))
}
```