# How to run html on a Go server

Tags: html, go, server

I've created a server in Go and I'm trying to run an html file in the browser. But the browser just prints out the code like a txt file instead of rendering the html formatting. My index.html file is saved in the /public directory.

My go code looks like this:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", new(MyHandler))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}

type MyHandler struct {
    http.Handler
}

func (this *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := "public/" + req.URL.Path
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(path))

    if err == nil {
        w.Write(data)
    } else {
        w.WriteHeader(404)
        w.Write([]byte("404 - " + http.StatusText(404)))
    }

}
```

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server

Comment: Please show the value you expect `data` to hold after this line; `data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(string(path))`.

Comment: You are sending almost no header (only the absolute minimum what package http adds). This is bad. If you want your browser to process the data you send as HTML you should tell him: Set the Content-Type header to e.g. "text/html".

Answer (score 0):

In your main try using `http.HandleFunc("/", ServeHTTP)` then edit the `ServeHTTP` method so it doesn't have a reciever ie; `func ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)`

You attempt to use that object and the `Handle` method may work fine too (if implemented correctly) but most of the examples use `HandleFunc` and if you do as well I bet your problem will go away.

The only other thing that would be causing the issues you're observing is a failure to read the file who's contents are assigned to `data` or some misconception about what the data in that file actually is.

Comment: The `ServeHTTP` method on `MyHandler` allows it to satisfy `http.Handler` and hence work with `http.Handler` (which expects the interface)—although you probably know this. It's definitely a clunky way to call a handler though: falling back to writing `http.HandleFunc("/", MyHandler)` is better. `ServeHTTP` should really only be used as a method.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you're just reading the contents of the file and writing it out. Since Go can't tell *what* type of file it is, it can't set the header.

Thankfully, there's a useful `http.ServeFile` function [in the net/http package](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) that can help you.

```
func (this *MyHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    path := "public/" + req.URL.Path
    http.ServeFile(w, r, filepath.Join("path/to/file", path))
}
```

`http.ServeFile` attempts to set the `Content-Type` based on the file extension or first handful of bytes (for a HTML file it should get it right).

A better solution is to make your route handler the `http.FileServer`

```
func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public"))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

Take a look at the [examples in the Go docs](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) for how to use it in other ways.

Shameless plug: I wrote a small middleware library that makes it a bit easier to serve static files in Go that you may find use in (or read just read the code for insight): https://github.com/elithrar/station

Answer (score 0):

Start with getting the HTML up and running.  Then, build in your HTTP error handling (e.g. 404).  I recommend using the `text/template` from the start, even if you're not adding any dynamism to your app... yet!

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", RootHandler)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func RootHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("public/index.html")
    t := template.New("")
    t, _ = t.Parse(string(file))

    t.Execute(res, nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to hold off on using the `text/template` package and just serve the HTML straight up, simply read your `index.html` file and write it to the response writer (e.g. `res` for response in my example, however many folks also use `w` for writer).

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", RootHandler)

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func RootHandler(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("public/index.html")
    res.Write(file)
}
```