# Serving a single page application with go net/http mux

Tags: http, go, reactjs

I'm building an api that also serves my react front end app, but am having an issue serving my index.html

Given that it's not really a go template I'm not using html/template.

I'm not seeing a strait forward way to serve the static html root of my app on all pages that do not start /api in the route.

I'm purposely trying not to use any go frameworks beyond gorilla's mux

My handler.go:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views"))
}
```

Routes.go:

```
type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

var routes = Routes{
    Route{
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },
}
```

router.go

```
import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {

    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler

        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(handler)

    }

    return router
}
```

main:

```
package main

import (
    "./server"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    router := server.NewRouter()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

Currently a blank page shows up, and thats it.  My index.html is located in `/views/index.html` in relation to the executable (but I've tried it in relation to the handler as well)

**Update**

I was able to serve the html file using the method shown in this question: [How do you serve a static html file using a go web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server)  However using mux and the more modularized file structure still yields a nice pretty, clean blank page.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to serve the static content with Go? You could setup nginx to serve static content and forward everything else to your Go program.

Comment: I don't have experience using nginx and I know it is doable with go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In handler.go, your Index function is actually a no-op, since `http.FileServer()` returns a Handler, which is never passed the ResponseWriter or Request, hence the blank page.

Maybe try something like this to at least get past that:

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.FileServer(http.Dir("./views")).ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

Comment: Bingo, I was thinking it might have something to do with the lack of action on the ResponseWriter.  Unfortunately my other static files in that folder (css and js) are not coming through.

Comment: I think that's because of how specific the route pattern is. Even index.html won't come back if you call it by name, only as '/'. Perhaps something like "/{file}" instead of "/", depending on how that interacts with other routes you have (though you might not want to be serving all of your static content out of the root path anyway).

Comment: I'm actually serving out of a /dist (not /views as seen above) folder.  /{file} is getting a 404 as well

Comment: I added a PathPrefix to the router
``` router.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./dist")))
```

and now my other files are being served