# Why my fileServer handler doesn't work?

Tags: http, go, fileserver

I've a simple folder :

```
Test/
    main.go
    Images/
          image1.png
          image2.png
          index.html
```

In main main.go I just put :

```
package main

import (
       "net/http"
)

func main(){
     fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./Images"))
     http.Handle("/Images/*", fs)
     http.ListenAndServe(":3003", nil)
}
```

But when I curl on *http://localhost:3003/Images/* or even I add to path file's name, it doesn't work.
I don't understand because it's the same as the reply given on
[this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server)

Can you tell me so that this does not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `*` and add extra sub-folder `Images`:
This works fine:

```
Test/
    main.go
    Images/
          Images/
                image1.png
                image2.png
                index.html
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./Images"))
    http.Handle("/Images/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3003", nil)
}
```

Then `go run main.go`

And:

http://localhost:3003/Images/

---

Or simply use:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./Images"))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3003", nil)
}
```

with:
http://localhost:3003/

Answer (score 1):

The reason the request failed to return what you expected is because they did not match the pattern defined in the `http.Handle(pattern string, handler Handler)` call. The [ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) documentation provides a description of how to compose patterns. Any request is prefixed matched from most specific to least specific. It appears as though you have assumed a glob pattern can be used. Your handler would have been invoked with requests to `/Images/*<file system path>`.  You need to define a directory path like so, `Images/`.

On a side note, it is worth considering how your program gets the directory path to serve files from. Hard coding a relative means your program will only function within a specific location within the filesystem which incredibly brittle. You could use a command line argument to allow users to specify a path or use a configuration file parsed at runtime. These considerations make your program easy to modularize and test.

Answer (score 0):

Dot in ./Images refer cwd current working directory, not you project root. For your server to work you must run it from Test/ directory, or address Images with absolute rooted path.