# Open html file base on net/http package in Go

Tags: http, go, web, server

I am a beginner for Go.
I try to build a static web server in my local computer.
Actually, I have been read [How do you serve a static html file using a go web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server)

My question is, if I have a `Home.html`.
I want to open `Home.html` when I link `localhost:7777`.

It's like `index.html`, but I want to replace `index.html` with `Home.html`.

Here is my code:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello world!")
}
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", helloHandler)
    // 
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":7777", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe", err)
    } else {
        log.Println("listen 7777")
    }
}
```

How do I re-write this code?

What keywords for this problem?

Comment: The quoted code doesn't serve any static files, so "how do I modify this code to do something completely different" is too broad a question. Can you narrow it down to some particular issue you're having?

Answer (score 2):

To serve any static file to an endpoint, you can use `http.ServeFile` or `http.ServeContent` if you want more control.

In this case, you can write:

```
func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w,r,"Home.html")
}
```

Be sure to set the name to the path of `Home.html`. It is possible for the program to not find the file when using a relative path when running from elsewhere.