# How to serve a lot of pages

Tags: go

I want to create a web server with many subpages. For example

www.mainpage.com - main page and I have many subpages

www.mainpage.com/1page; www.mainpage.com/2page; www.mainpage.com/3page; ..... www.mainpage.com/999page

I have no idea how to handle all of this pages. I think that this way isn't correct

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/1page", PageHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/2page", PageHandler)
    ......
    http.HandleFunc("/999page", PageHandler)

    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [`http.HandleFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) says:

> The documentation for ServeMux explains how patterns are matched.

[`ServeMux`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux) says:

> Note that since a pattern ending in a slash names a rooted subtree, the pattern "/" matches all paths not matched by other registered patterns, not just the URL with Path == "/".

The [`Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) object passed to the handler function contains the request `URL`.

So just register a single pattern at the root:

```
    http.HandleFunc("/", PageHandler)
```

Comment: Thanks! And what if i Have many subsub....pages, like ```mainpage/1page/2page/3page....```

Comment: *"matches all paths"* -- it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried serving static files?

Check this answer: [How do you serve a static html file using a go web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server#26563418)

```golang
package main

import (
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

If you do not want to use static files and only `http.Handler`, you can use a loop to register your handler function. For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    for i := 1; i < 1000; i++ {
        http.HandleFunc(fmt.Sprintf("/%dpage", i), PageHandler(i))
    }
    fmt.Println("Server is listening...")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}

func PageHandler(i int) func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) {
    return func(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        resp.WriteHeader(200)
        resp.Write([]byte(strconv.Itoa(i)))
    }
}
```