# In Golang, how do I get the params like DOCUMENT_ROOT or others from FastCGI (Request object)?

Tags: go

I'm aware of how to retrieve GET query params through the Request object, but I can't for the life of me find out how to params like 'DOCUMENT_ROOT'.

Listed below is the 'params' object passed through Deno FCGI for reference, and I think it's the same for PHP in $_SERVER. Many of these are easy to get in different ways in Go's Request object, but some are not. A couple I have bolded (or attempted to bold with stars) because I need to get them from the webserver which is calling my FCGI Go application. But I can't find them in the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request)!

EDIT: GO is **not** the webserver. GO is the FastCGI server through which the webserver (in my case NGINX, but could be any) connects to via a unix socket. Technically this could be an NGINX problem - not passing the appropriate params through FCGI - but I doubt it otherwise it would be a much bigger issue and people's applications would be breaking everywhere.

```
GATEWAY_INTERFACE
SERVER_SOFTWARE
SERVER_PROTOCOL
REQUEST_METHOD
**SCRIPT_FILENAME** => /var/myserver/www/public_html/test.html
SCRIPT_NAME => /test.html
**DOCUMENT_ROOT** => /var/myserver/www/public_html/
REMOTE_ADDR => 9.9.9.9
REMOTE_PORT => 65196
SERVER_ADDR => 81.82.83.34
SERVER_NAME => test.com
SERVER_ADMIN => 
SERVER_PORT => 443
REQUEST_SCHEME => https
REQUEST_URI => /test.html?test=blah
HTTPS => on
X_SPDY => HTTP3
SSL_PROTOCOL => QUIC
SSL_CIPHER => TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE => 128
SSL_CIPHER_ALGKEYSIZE => 128
HTTP_ACCEPT => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING => gzip, deflate, br
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE => en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7
HTTP_COOKIE => _ga=GA1.1.643677563.1631966551;
HTTP_HOST => test.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.71 Safari/537.36
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA => "Chromium";v="94", "Google Chrome";v="94", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_MOBILE => ?0
HTTP_SEC_CH_UA_PLATFORM => "macOS"
HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS => 1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_SITE => none
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_MODE => navigate
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_USER => ?1
HTTP_SEC_FETCH_DEST => document
```

Comment: `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is a PHP parameter, *not* a CGI parameter: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html

Comment: Not true - check out /path/to/nginx/fastcgi.conf ... DOCUMENT_ROOT should be passed, along with SCRIPT_NAME and many others.

Actually, I realize slightly that I am an idiot - however not completely. ProcessEnv (https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/fcgi#ProcessEnv) in the fcgi module actually solves 50% of my problem. But some variables are still not being passed.

DOCUMENT_ROOT is being passed now when running ProcessEnv(request), but many many are missing, among them SCRIPT_NAME which is included in NGINX's fastcgi.conf alongside DOCUMENT_ROOT - which means it should be being passed also

Comment: golang it's not a webserver. It doesn't process static files and therefore does not have a root. perhaps this is implemented in some third-party packages, but definitely not in net

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you serve a static html file using a go web server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26559557/how-do-you-serve-a-static-html-file-using-a-go-web-server)

Comment: I should have been more clear. GO is not the web server. GO is the FastCGI server through which the web server (in my case NGINX, but could be any) connects to via a unix socket. Technically this could be an NGINX problem - not passing the appropriate params through FCGI - but I doubt it otherwise it would be a much bigger issue and people's applications would be breaking everywhere

Comment: @spiilmusic Go is a language, its standard library `net/http` includes a web server, which will serve static files, among other things. But none of that is relevant for a Go application running as a CGI application.

Comment: @Adrian I agree. I just want to hear from Pete more information about this cgi app. Which lib was used, etc.

Comment: Pretty much just https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/fcgi. You see there the ProcessEnv function which I mentioned above that answered half my problem, but there are still tons of missing params. I was able to get DOCUMENT_ROOT from that but not SCRIPT_NAME which is also important. I can use regex to get it from the request URI but I'd rather find out how to make it work properly from the get-go